# Failed to load PDF file -reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, pdfjs-dist

i'm new to ReactJs and i would like to display the PDF file as an image. However, I am consistently encountering an error stating "failed to load pdf file." Additionally, I attempted to switch from using the  element to , but unfortunately, the PDF is still not being displayed.

here is my code.

```
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf'

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

function Bridging()
{
//display pdf as image
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    const [loadingError, setLoadingError] = useState(null);
  
    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
      setNumPages(numPages);
    };
  
    const onPageChange = (page) => {
      setPageNumber(page);
    };

    const onLoadError = (error) => {
      setLoadingError(error.message); 
    };

return(
 <div className='pdfcont'>
                    {fileList.map((url)=>{
                        return <iframe type="application/pdf" onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                        onLoadError={onLoadError} renderMode="canvas" 
                        file={url} width='100%' height='100%'/>
                          
                          
                    })}
</div>


}
export default Bridging
```

I would like to display the pdf file into image.